# How to prevent the cursor from moving when modifying an input's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I'm creating a numeric input mask/value pair by showing the user a text input to give it several stylings (i.e. dividing thousands with a comma), and storing the real value to be sent to the form in a hidden number input.

Right now I'm noticing that editing the value of the visible input updates the selection index to the very end, which is unintuitive when you edit the input from i.e. [the middle of the value](https://i.gyazo.com/a9e2869e3f1fa622694f04495f951eed.mp4). I understand that the position has been lost since the value is being completely rewritten, but how can I manually keep track of it to update it back, given that the `on.('input')` event handler triggers "after" the value has already changed and the `keydown` event happens before the modification takes place?

```js
$("#foo").on('change paste input mouseup', function() {
  const validation_decimals = 3 //allowed decimal places
  const $mask = $('#foo')
  const $value = $('#baz')
  let hasDot = $mask.val().includes('.')
  let nValue = $mask.val().replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "").replace(/[!¡@#$%^&\/+*()=¿?":;\[\]\-_~`\\{}'|<>]/g, "")

  // only one period allowed
  if (hasDot) {
    if ($mask.val().match(/\./g).length > 1) {
      let newVal = $mask.val()
      const lastDot = newVal.lastIndexOf('.')
      newVal = newVal.slice(0, lastDot) + newVal.slice(lastDot + 1)
      $mask.val(newVal)
    }
  }
  $value.val(parseFloat($mask.val().replace(/,/g, "")))

  // adding comma-based thousands grouping
  let [integers, decimals] = $value.val().toString().split('.')
  if (integers.length > 3) {
    for (let iReverse = -3; iReverse > -integers.length; iReverse -= 4) {
      integers = integers.slice(0, iReverse) + ',' + integers.slice(iReverse)
    }
  }

  let fValue = integers

  if (hasDot) {
    fValue += '.'
  }

  if (decimals !== undefined) {
    fValue += decimals
  }

  $('#foo').val(fValue)
})

// preventing more decimal places than allowed and user-inputted commas.
$("#foo").on('select click keydown', function(e) {
  let selStart = e.target.selectionStart;
  let selEnd = e.target.selectionEnd;
  const isComma = e.keyCode == 188
  const isNumber = (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)
  const validation_decimals = 3
  if ($(this).val().includes('.')) {
    const value = $(this).val()
    const decimals = value.split('.')[value.split('.').length - 1]
    const decimalLengthReached = decimals.length == validation_decimals
    const selectionBeforePeriod = selStart < value.indexOf('.') || selEnd > selStart
    if (isNumber && decimalLengthReached && !selectionBeforePeriod) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }
  if (isComma) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```css
.input-group {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label for='foo'>User Field (type here)</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id='foo' step='0.01' aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  </div>
  <label for='baz'><em>Hidden field</em></label>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="number" id='baz' aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" step='0.1'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `selectionStart` property of the input fields to determine where the caret was before you completely rewrite the input field.

```
document.querySelector("#my-input").addEventListener("change", function() {
  // Get the position of the caret before you rewrite the input field
  let caretPosition = document.querySelector("#my-input").selectionStart;

  // Rewrite the input field here

  // Put the caret back to where it was
  document.querySelector("#my-input").selectionStart = caretPosition;
});
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know the property was that easily accessible. And just to expand on the solution, you can also modify this value via jquery using `$("#name").selectionStart = value`, instead of `$("#name").selectionStart(value)` or `$("#name").prop('selectionStart', value)` as one would (perhaps erroneously) expect.